# Submit form on Switchery (checkbox) state change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using [Switchery](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/) on one of my form designed using Asp.Net MVC. Now, I would like to submit form to the IIS server when its state changes. I tried following code but no luck.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.switchery').on('click',function(){
            $('form').submit();
        });
    });
```

Any help on how to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with the following code.

```
        $(document).on('click', '.switchery', function () {
            $('form').submit();
        })
```

Hope it will be helpful to someone.